# Flash Animation in an Android App - Options?

Tags: android, flash, android-animation

Let me first state that I am no programmer, so this may seem like a stupid question.  I have done all kinds of searching on this question, and answers seem far-and-wide, and have only left me more confused.

I am currently accepting bids for the development of an Android app version of our graphic novel:  http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Flash-Android/Android-Tablet-App-for-Graphic.html

One of the issues/problems from my requirements document that has been raised more than once by bidders is about the Flash animation http://www.newbabyproductions.com/other/intro_files/ChronicArgoIntro_v2_em.swf that I want to be used in the title screen, and how that will be implemented in the app.  The initial programmer that I was working with had real problems with and was never able to get it to work.  I know that in order to use the swf file as-is, Flash needs to be installed on the devices, and that is not an Android standard.  So I want to know what options there are to be able to include this.

A couple bidders have suggested that the animation be converted to video.  And although they claim that they could still make it work correctly, I worry about losing the looping that is built into the animation.

Can the animation be converted to or re-created with Java?

Should I be looking into using FLash Builder and/or Adobe AIR?

We will eventually be porting this app for Apple iPads as well, so if there is an option that woks for both Android and iOS, that would be better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest converting it to video, any experienced programmer will easily be able to loop the video, I did a little research though, you may want to check out this link:

> http://wiki.colorinfection.com/index.php/How_to_create_an_Android_app_from_a_Flash_.swf_file_with_Adobe_AIR_SDK

I haven't read through it entirely, just scanned through but it seems that you can convert SWF files to Android applications through Adobe Air SDK. Good luck, zeokila.

> EDIT: The device must have Adobe Air installed.

Comment: Thanks zeokila.  Just to be clear, I don't mean that the whole animation loops; just a portion will loop.  The animation is about 9 seconds, of which the last 1.5 seconds is in an infinite loop.  Can that be done with video?

Comment: Don't worry, I understood as I saw your animation, a programmer with enough experience would be able to loop it at specific points. I personnaly do not know, I am new at coding, but I know it is possible, and probably even simple for an experienced programmer.